# Object doesn't fade-out

Tags: jquery

I'm re-using the following JavaScript to make a object fade out when clicked, but the object doesn't make fade out animation. Anyone can help-me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $curtainopen = false;

        $(".sticker").click(function(){
            $(this).blur();
            if ($curtainopen == false){ 
                $(this).stop().fadeOut(1600, "linear", complete); 
                $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({top:'-2000px'}, 6000 );
                $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({bottom:'-2000px'},6000 );
                $curtainopen = true;
            }else{
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'50%'}, 2000 );
                $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'51%'}, 2000 );
                $curtainopen = false;
            }
            return false;
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

here's the original javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $curtainopen = false;

        $(".sticker").click(function(){
            $(this).blur();
            if ($curtainopen == false){ 
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '-300px' }, {queue:false, duration:1000, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({top:'-2000px'}, 6000 );
                $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({bottom:'-2000px'},6000 );
                $curtainopen = true;
            }else{
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'50%'}, 2000 );
                $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'51%'}, 2000 );
                $curtainopen = false;
            }
            return false;
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: It'd help if you posted your markup, makes it easier for us to play with it in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
$(this).fadeOut();
```

instead of

```
$(this).stop().fadeOut(1600, "linear", complete);
```